# How can I automate this task in Notepad++

Tags: script, notepad++, shell-script

I've a text file with around 200+ table names. Sample like this

```
T_BCPCOMITEE_EA4
T_BCPEMERSIT_EA4
T_BCPROLE_EA4
T_BDR_AG_EA4
T_BDR_CRITERIA_EA4
```

I need to take the table name and add a select statement the final end output should be like htis

```
--T_BCPCOMITEE_EA4
select * from T_BCPCOMITEE_EA4;
--T_BCPEMERSIT_EA4
select * from T_BCPEMERSIT_EA4;
--T_BCPROLE_EA4
select * from T_BCPROLE_EA4;
--T_BDR_AG_EA4
select * from T_BDR_AG_EA4;
--T_BDR_CRITERIA_EA4
select * from T_BDR_CRITERIA_EA4;
```

Is there any way I can automate this task. Please help. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to do a regex find and replace.

This is done by either going to `Search` on the toolbar and then selecting `Replace...`, or by using the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Ensure that you've got `Regular expression` selected in the bottom right and ensure that `. matches newline` is unchecked (this is important for the regex to work as intended).

*NOTE: This regex solution is assuming that each line has a separate and complete table name (as in, no table names are split across multiple lines and each line only contains a single table name).*

Put the following into the "Find" box:

```
^(.*)
```

Put the following into the "Replace" box:

```
--\1\nSELECT * FROM \1;
```

## Explanation

The regex string can be broken down as follows:

The `^` is a start of line anchor and makes sure that the regex matches the very start of each line. This ensures that it doesn't accidentally pick up extra lines.

The `(.*)` group is used to match any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`) and then to make those matched characters available to the replace string (`()`) using the placeholder format of `$x`, where x is the group number (which increases sequentially, with `1` being the first, `2` being the second and so on).

The replace string can be broken down as follows:

`--\1` is used to print two literal `-` characters, followed by all the characters that were matched in the regex (the `(.*)` group), which are inserted in place of `\1`.

The `\n` is used to add a new line into the replace string (`\r\n` may need to be used instead depending on your operating system, but I'm currently going on the assumption that `\n` alone will work).

The `SELECT * FROM \1;` section is used to print the string as seen, except `\1` is replaced with the matched characters as before (which will be the table name).

Comment: Thanks for the quick turn around. The solution works but the only problem is table name is being replaced by $1. Any tuning for this?

Comment: @RaMs_YearnsToLearn If you've got the regex option selected in the lower left corner of the find and replace panel, I'm not sure why it wouldn't be replacing it as stated. I tried running the above against the data that you provided and I was getting the output that you linked. In theory, it should either be matching both with regex or neither, not only applying regex matching to the `find` field. Is the rest of the output working, except for the table name?

Comment: @RaMs_YearnsToLearn Actually, upon further inspection, it seems that you can use the format `\1` instead of `$1` (although I'm unsure why it would work on my machine and not yours). Does making this change in the replace string fix the issue? If so, I'll update the answer with the extra details.

Comment: I replaced $1 with \1 and it worked. Thanks a lot.